# Bhagavad Gita 12 3-4 endorses Advaita as a valid, though hard way for realization. Why do schools who worship a personal Brahman condemn Advaita?

Tags: advaita

https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/12/verse/3-4

> ये त्वक्षरमनिर्देश्यमव्यक्तं पर्युपासते |
> सर्वत्रगमचिन्त्यञ्च कूटस्थमचलन्ध्रुवम् || 3||
> सन्नियम्येन्द्रियग्रामं सर्वत्र समबुद्धय: |
> ते प्राप्नुवन्ति मामेव सर्वभूतहिते रता: || 4||

> BG 12.3-4: But those who worship the formless aspect of the Absolute Truth—the imperishable, the indefinable, the unmanifest, the all-pervading, the unthinkable, the unchanging, the eternal, and the immoveable—by restraining their senses and being even-minded everywhere, such persons, engaged in the welfare of all beings, also attain Me.

> क्लेशोऽधिकतरस्तेषामव्यक्तासक्तचेतसाम् ||
> अव्यक्ता हि गतिर्दु:खं देहवद्भिरवाप्यते || 5||

> BG 12.5: For those whose minds are attached to the unmanifest, the path of realization is full of tribulations. Worship of the unmanifest is exceedingly difficult for embodied beings.

But here is a Madhwite commentary on Advaita:

https://gurucharana.wordpress.com/2015/06/20/madwaamruthamaharnava/

> [11] If one leaves the MadhwaShaastra and instead goes and studies Adhvaitha, then that person is willingly entering the
> deepest and goriest of all hells, ie the andhatamas.

Answer (score 2):

Acharya Madhava interprets those verses differently. According to him, the 'Avyakta' or the 'unmanifest' of BG 12.3-5 Refers to 'prakriti' or Sri/Lakshmi and not the formless aspect of the absolute.

Here are some snippets of his commentaries on those verses.

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can read the full commentary [here](https://archive.org/details/bhagavadgita_bhashya_and_tatparya_nirnaya_of_madhvacharya_-_nagesh_d_sonde/page/n187/mode/2up?view=theater).